# Use Action or FUNC in dictionaries

Tags: c#

i was wondering if it is possible to pass a template into a function like this example:

```
 Dictionary<string, Action<object>> myDict= new Dictionary<string, Action<object>>();
 myDict.Add("someString",(nameOfMethod));
```

this method for example is a setter so it receives as a parameter (double or string or int etc...) and return void.

i suppose the following is impossible..
(i got this ERROR  : Error The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>.Add(string, System.Action)' has some invalid arguments)

any ideas how to do it?

Comment: What is the **actual code** that threw the error? I don't think it's the dictionary that's the issue.

Comment: I just pasted your code verbatim and it compiles fine. Did you try to debug anything?

Comment: @Brandon: I suspect your method declaration has a parameter of type `object` rather than `double` or `string`...

Comment: @JonSkeet It did. When I compiled it I just automatically knew not to pass it that. By the time I realized the issue, you'd already posted your answer. You're too quick for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> this method for example is a setter so it receives as a parameter (double or string or int etc...) and return void.

That's the problem - a method accepting a `double` isn't applicable for `Action<object>`, because an `Action<object>` should be able to be invoked with *any* `object` reference as the argument.

You can use a lambda expression to cast and convert though:

```
myDict.Add("somestring", o => MethodAcceptingDouble((double) o));
```

You could even write a helper method to do it, although unfortunately due to limitations of type inference you need to specify the type argument explicitly.

```
static class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action<object>>();
        AddAction<double>(dictionary, "somestring", SampleMethod);
    }

    static void AddAction<T>(Dictionary<string, Action<object>> dictionary,
                             string name,
                             Action<T> action)
    {
        dictionary.Add(name, arg => action((T) arg));
    }

    static void SampleMethod(double input)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, of course! Oh, and by the way, your answer on my question yesterday was right. If you'll undelete I can up vote and accept.

Comment: it works great!! thank you !! :)
can you explain me please this line?

dictionary.Add(name, arg => action((T) arg));

Comment: @omri_saadon: Which bit of it is confusing you?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: arg => (what does the arrow means?)

Comment: @omri_saadon: That's a lambda expression. If you haven't seen lambda expressions before, look them up on MSDN or in a good C# book. They're too big a topic to explain in a comment.